# Are there any alternatives to vim-latex?

Tags: vim, vim-latex, ide

Are there any good alternative plugins that someone has put together for working with latex in `vim`?

I use the `vim-latex` [latex suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/), but it's a bit much. I'm pretty sure I use maybe 10% of the features - and I don't really like some of the design choices. However, it is much better than nothing. I'd just like something more lightweight, with just a few basic macros, code highlighting, folding, compiling, etc.

Comment: [Vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) is nice. There is also a list of alternatives with a summary of the main differences between the packages. Also look here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/what-are-the-differences-between-latex-plugins

Comment: There are four different options for Vim listed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides

Comment: Thanks - both helpful. This answer in particular was what I was looking for: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5747/20985

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is one tool for one job :

### Code highlighting : just vim

In `.vimrc` : `syntax on`

### Folding : just vim

In `.vimrc` : `set fdm=marker`
Commands : `zc`, `zo`, `zr`, `zm`.
I open and close a section with `%{{{1` and `%}}}`, a subsection with `%{{{2` `%}}}`. A long TikZ code goes in `%{{{` and `%}}}`= so it is immune to `zr` or `zm`.

### Spell checking : just vim

In *ftplugin/tex.vim* (`filetype plugin on` in `.vimrc`):
`setlocal spell`
In normal mode:
- `zg` (add **Good** word to local dict.).
- `zw` (remove **wrong** word from local dict.)

### Compiling 1 : just vim8.1

`:term latexmk -pdf -pv %`

### Compiling 2 : latexmk *(in tmux using Dispatch in vim)*

1. When pressing `<LocalLeader>L`, **latexmk** compiles in the background and the pdf shows up on success. On failure, I press `:Copen` to view the error messages in a vim split.
2. When pressing `<LocalLeader>l`, **latexmk** spits out its output in a  vim split (actually in a tmux split during compilation) and the pdf shows up.

Here are the commands in `ftplugin/tex.vim`:

```
nnoremap <LocalLeader>l :w<CR> :Dispatch  latexmk -pdf -pv -halt-on-error %<CR>
nnoremap <LocalLeader>L :w<CR> :Dispatch! latexmk -pdf -pv -halt-on-error %<CR>
```

### Code checking / Linting : ALE (using chktex)

In `ftplugin/tex.vim` (`filetype plugin on` in `.vimrc`) :

```
execute "packadd ale"
let b:ale_fixers = ['remove_trailing_lines',  'trim_whitespace']
let b:ale_linters = ['chktex’]
```

*NOTE*: To ignore the error type 6 at a particular line, I add that to its end `% chktek 6`

### Grammar checking : vim-grammarous

In *ftplugin/tex.vim* (`filetype plugin on` in `.vimrc`):

```
execute "packadd vim-grammarous"
nnoremap <LocalLeader>g   :GrammarousCheck --lang=fr<CR>
vnoremap <LocalLeader>g   :'<,'>GrammarousCheck --lang=fr<CR>
nnoremap <LocalLeader>G   :GrammarousReset<CR>
```

Comment: How you have managed to use `vim-grammarous` with `latex`? it check syntaxes also, and gives error there, right from `\documentclass`.